# How can I use Windows after installing Ubuntu in Windows?

Tags: windows, wubi

I recently installed Ubuntu. I didn't install it from a disk, I downloaded it directly from the site and installed from Windows. Is there a way to maybe switch back to Windows now? I want to in order to use iTunes and sync my iPhone.

Comment: If you installed Ubuntu using [Wubi](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer), then you should be able to choose to boot Windows. Just choose the Windows option instead of the Ubuntu option after you turn on your computer.

Answer (score 3):

You are, in effect, asking about a few different possibilities, already covered by some existing questions:

- Yes, you can [dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/q/107538/22949) Ubuntu and Windows. This should already be working for you though, as a Wubi system (like yours) is dual-boot. This means that when you turn your computer on, you should be presented with a menu of two choices: Ubuntu and Windows. Simply select the operating system you want to boot that operating system.
- Alternatively you can [run Windows in a virtual machine and connect your iPhone 5 via USB to the virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/q/19286/22949).
- You might interested in this question: [Is it possible yet to synchronise music to an iPhone running iOS 5/6?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218838) for information on the possibility of syncing your iPhone in Ubuntu.

You cannot seamlessly switch between your Ubuntu system and your Windows system, without rebooting, except by creating a virtual machine. (And if you do that, it will be a separate virtual system, not the same Windows system as is installed normally. Your Windows partition hosts the disk image containing your Wubi installation of Ubuntu, making virtualizing the installed system itself even more difficult and risky than it ordinarily would.)

If you need more details or need help getting any of these to work, you can edit your question to provide more details.